# Find the invertible elements and zero divisors in the ring $(\mathbb{Z}_{21}, +, \cdot)$. For each invertible element find the inverse.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory, congruences

this is the exercise I have:

In the ring $(\mathbb{Z}_{21}, +, \cdot)$:
i) Find the invertible elements;
ii) Find the zero divisors;
iii) For each invertible element find the inverse.

I have done this:
i)
since the $gcd(a,n) = 1$ where $a \ne 0\in \mathbb{Z}_{21}$ and $n = 21$, then the element $a$ has an inverse.
Or also, since $21 = 7 \cdot 3$, if  $7 \nmid a \mbox{ and } 3 \nmid a$, then  $a$ has an inverse.
Considering the things above, I have found them by inspection: $1,2,4,5,8,10,11,13,16,17,19,20$.
I know that they are few elements, and by attempts it is a good way, but, is there exists any algorithm to calculate them in a more rapid way?

ii)
since the $gcd(a,n) \ne 1$, or also since $21 = 7 \cdot 3$, if $7 \mid a \mbox{ and } 3 \mid a$, then $a$ is a zero divisor. So, by attempts, the zero divisors are $3,6,7,9,12,14,15,18$
Also, here, is there any other rapid algorithm to determine them?

iii)
for each invertible element must hold the following:
$$ax \equiv 1 \mbox{ (mod 21) }$$
so,
$1x \equiv 1 \mbox{ (mod 21) }$
hence $1$ is the inverse of $1$.
$2x \equiv 1 \mbox{ (mod 21) }$
it means to solve this equation in $\mathbb{Z}_{21}$:
$\begin{array}{rcl}[2] \odot [x] & = & [1] \\ [2 \cdot x] & = & [1] \\ [2 \cdot 11 ] & = & [1] \\ [22] & = & [1] \\ [1] & = & [1]\end{array}$
so here the inverse of $2$ is $x = 11$.

In my book there is a hint:
check if these following numbers are congruent modulo 21, they will help you to find the inverses:
$22,43,64,85,106,127,148,169,190,211,399=21 \cdot 19$
but, I don't know how to use them.
Can you tell me anything about them?

Please, can you give any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Note that $1\equiv 1+21\equiv 22$ and similarly $1\equiv 1+2\cdot 21 \equiv 43$ etc... so the list of numbers they give you are all elements of the equivalence class of $1$.  The hint is giving you a (*partial*) list of possible elements you can look for as outcomes of multiplications for elements to find the inverses with.  E.g. $4\cdot 37=148$ and $148$ is on the list so therefore...

Comment: @JMoravitz Can you add some other details as answer below? I would want to accept your answer as the best one.

Comment: Note that if $ax\equiv1\pmod{21}$ then $x$ is the inverse of $a$, but also $a$ is the inverse of $x$. In particular $a$ and $x$ are both units. You have already listed all $12$ units, so now you need only to pair them up correctly. This is a matter of performing a few multiplications; as always $1^{-1}=1$ and $20^{-1}=(-1)^{-1}=-1=20$. This leaves $10$ elements to pair off.

Comment: Moreover, as you have $20\times20\equiv1$ and $20=2\times10=4\times5$, you immediately get
\begin{eqnarray*}
2^{-1}&=&10\times20&=&11\\
4^{-1}&=&5\times20&=&16\\
5^{-1}&=&4\times20&=&17\\
10^{-1}&=&2\times20&=&19,
\end{eqnarray*}
leaving just the units $8$ and $13$. A quick check shows that $8\times13\neq1$ so $8^2=13^2=1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we need :

$\begin{array}{rcl}
2x & \equiv & 1  & (\mod 21) & \Rightarrow \\ 
(2\times11 )x & \equiv & 1\times11 &( \mod 21)& \Rightarrow \\ 
x & \equiv & 11 &( \mod 21)& \end{array}$

$\begin{array}{rcl}
4x & \equiv & 1 & (\mod 21) & \Rightarrow \\ 
(4\times5 )x & \equiv & 1\times5 & (\mod21)&  \Rightarrow \\
-x &\equiv& 5 &(\mod 21)& \Rightarrow \\ 
x &\equiv&  -5& (\mod 21)&  \\ & \equiv & 16& (\mod 21)& \end{array}$

$\begin{array}{rcl}
5x & \equiv & 1 & (\mod 21) & \Rightarrow \\
(4\times5 )x &\equiv & 1\times4 &(\mod21)& \Rightarrow \\
-x &\equiv& 4 &(\mod 21)& \Rightarrow \\
x &\equiv& -4 &(\mod 21)& \\ &\equiv& 17 &(\mod 21)& \end{array}$

$\begin{array}{rcl}
8x &\equiv& 1 &(\mod 21)& \Rightarrow \\
(2\times8 )x &\equiv& 1\times2 &(\mod21)& \Rightarrow \\
-5x &\equiv& 2 &(\mod 21)& \Rightarrow \\ 
-20x &\equiv& 8 &(\mod 21)& \Rightarrow \\ 
x &\equiv& 8 &(\mod 21)& \end{array}$

$\vdots$

and other elements in same way

Comment: it is not clear ... why after $-20x \equiv 8 \mbox{ (mod 21) }$ follows $\equiv 17$?

Comment: Soory, I copy last step , then edit and I forgot remove $\equiv 17$  . I edit my answer, $-20\equiv 1 (mod 21)$, not follows $\equiv 17$,

Answer (score 1):

Note: This is an unorthodox answer using claims that have not been verified by the mathematical community, but I couldn't resist taking the theory 'out for drive' and demonstrate how it doesn't 'fall off a cliff'.

Observe that when using this method we don't need [Euler's totient function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function) to get the count for the number of invertibles or identify them by checking for the numbers coprime to $21$. Rather, all the invertibles are 'lurking' in the factorization of larger numbers and are 'discovered' there by a 'combinatorial balancing' algorithm.

---

$\tag 1 1 \times 1 \equiv 1 \pmod{21}$

$\tag 2 20 \times 20 \equiv 1 \pmod{21}$

We will use our $\psi$[-theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3556728/432081) to find the remaining invertible elements.

$\quad 20,\quad \psi(20) = 110 \gt 21, \; \lambda(21,20) = 22 \;\,= 2 \times 11$
$\quad 19,\quad \psi(19) = 100 \gt 21, \; \lambda(21,19) = 43$
$\quad 18,\quad \psi(18) = 90 \;\,\gt 21, \; \lambda(21,18) = 64 \;\,= 2^6$
$\quad 17,\quad \psi(17) = 81 \;\,\gt 21, \; \lambda(21,17) = 85 \;\,= 5 \times 17$
$\quad 16,\quad \psi(16) = 72 \;\,\gt 21, \; \lambda(21,16) = 106 = 2 \times 53$
$\quad 15,\quad \psi(15) = 64 \;\,\gt 21, \; \lambda(21,15) = 127$
$\quad 14,\quad \psi(14) = 56 \;\,\gt 21, \; \lambda(21,14) = 148 = 2^2 \times 37$
$\quad 13,\quad \psi(13) = 49 \;\,\gt 21, \; \lambda(21,13) = 169 = {13}^2$
$\quad 12,\quad \psi(12) = 42 \;\,\gt 21, \; \lambda(21,12) = 190 = 2 \times 5 \times 19$
$\quad 11,\quad \psi(11) = 36 \;\,\gt 21, \; \lambda(21,11) = 211$
$\quad 10,\quad \psi(11) = 30 \;\,\gt 21, \; \lambda(21,10) = 232 = 2^3 \times 29$
$\quad 9,\quad \quad \psi(9) = 25 \;\,\gt 21, \; \lambda(21,9) \;= 253 = 11 \times 23$
$\quad 8,\quad \quad \psi(9) = 20 \;\,\le 21, \; \text{STOP}$

Presented with, say, $64 = 2^6$, a combinatorial 'balancing' argument must be used to get the inversion relationships, resulting in the 'uncovering' of

$\quad \overline 4 \times \overline 16 = \overline 1 \; \land \; \overline 8 \times \overline 8 = \overline 1$

and rejecting $2 \times 32 = 64$ since $32 \ge 21$.

Here are the invertbile integers $\text{modulo-}21$, that naturally come in pairs or singletons,

$\; 1$
$\; 2,11$
$\; 4,16$
$\; 8$
$\; 5,17$
$\; 13$
$\; 10,19$
$\; 20$