# Proving (or not) that two integer valued sequences are equal (featuring $ \lambda(n,k) = n^2 -kn + 1$).

Tags: recreational-mathematics

We are going to define two functions

$\quad \psi: \{3,4,5,6, \dots \} \to \{4,5,6,7, \dots \}$

and

$\quad \rho: \{3,4,5,6, \dots \} \to \{4,5,6,7, \dots \}$

where $\psi$ is defined using an algorithmic specification while $\rho$ is specified using recursion.

**The specification for $\psi$:**

We begin by introducing an auxiliary expression,

$\quad \lambda(n,k) = n^2 -kn + 1$

The function $\psi$ maps $k \in \{3,4,5,6, \dots \}$ as follows,

*For any $k \in \{3,5,6, \dots \}$ form the graph $C_k = \{\big(n, \lambda(n,k)\big) \mid n \ge k + 1\}$.*

*Find the smallest $N$ in the domain of $C_k$ such that for all $t \ge N$ the statement*

$\quad [\lambda(t,k) = ab] \land [1 \lt a \lt t] \land [1 \lt b \lt t]$

*is false.*

*Set $\psi(k) = N$.*

**The specification for $\rho$:**

$\quad \rho(3) = 4$
$\quad \rho(4) = 6$
$\quad \rho(5) = 9$

For $k \ge 6$
$\quad \text{If } \rho(k-1) - \rho(k-2) \ne \rho(k-2) - \rho(k-3) \text{ then } \rho(k) = 2 * \rho(k-1) - \rho(k-2) $
$\quad \text{else } \rho(k) = 2 * \rho(k-1) - \rho(k-2) + 1$

> Are these two functions are equal?
>
> If yes provide a proof.
>
> If not find a $k$ where $\psi(k) \ne \rho(k)$.

**My work**

The definition of $\psi$ came about as result of my (amateurish) foray into number theory; see

$\quad$[For $n \ge 4$ find a factorization $n^2 - 3n + 1 = ab$ where $a \lt n$ and $b \lt n$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3551615/432081)

The definition of $\psi$ is kind of involute/esoteric and I can't relate it to any work I've done before in mathematics, but the patterns it exhibits (including the internal algorithmic patterns) seem worth investigating and this is a good start.

I wasn't sure what tags to use for this so I chose only one, recreational-mathematics. If a specialist in some area of math thinks other tags should be included then they should edit this question and add them in.